# pyplot return unexpected contour paths

Tags: matplotlib, contour

I want to use `pyplot.contour` to extract isolines from 2D data.

My problem is that this method returns unexpected results : when I use `levels` clearly outside data range, the `contour` result still contains paths.

Here is an example reproducing the issue :

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

n = 256 
x = numpy.linspace(-3., 3., n) 
y = numpy.linspace(-3., 3., n) 
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y) 
Z = X * numpy.sinc(X ** 2 + Y ** 2) 
levels = [1000]

print(f'data min : {Z.min()}')
print(f'data min : {Z.max()}')
print(f'levels : {levels}')

isolines = pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, levels, colors='red')

for i, collection in enumerate(isolines.collections):
    npaths = len(collection.get_paths())
    print(f'collection[{i}] has {npaths} paths')

pyplot.show()
```

Which outputs

```
data min : -0.47993931267102286
data min : 0.47993931267102286
levels : [1000]
/path/to/issue.py:15: UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.
  isolines = pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, levels, colors='red')
collection[0] has 1 paths
```

[image]

I expected the contour to be empty and not contain 1 path, do I miss something obvious here ?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023/01/11, it is a bug in matplotlib :

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23778

As the fix has not landed yet, my temporary workaround is to detect when `levels` are outside `Z` value range, and empty the contour `collections` in that case.

```
quadcontourset = pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, levels)
zmin = numpy.min(Z)
zmax = numpy.max(Z)
inside = (levels > zmin) & (levels < zmax)
levels_in = levels[inside]
if not levels_in:
    quadcontourset.collections.clear()
```

I reproduce the issue with matplotlib `3.5.3`. The issue is not fixed in current `3.6.2` version but a fix seems on track at
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/24912